# Shisha Ushloshim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred thirty-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Ramech Everav?  (236 bones in the Mishaberach for Cholim).  Actually, ramach is 246, isn't it?  Bummer.

Comment: Ramach is 248!..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

geoffc's comment gave me an idea:

236 words in Krias Shema (out of the total of 248, including, as the case may be, א-ל מלך נאמן or the repetition of אני ה' אלקיכם or ה' אלקיכם אמת) are where we are accepting on ourselves Hashem's mitzvos. (The remaining 12 - the first verse of Shema, and ברוך שם - are the acceptance of His kingship.)

(Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 61:14)

Answer (score 1):

In a non-leap year, *Yom Yerushalayim* is the 236th day in the year if *Heshvan* and *Kislev* are both Mele'im (have 30 days):

*Tishrei*, *Heshvan*, *Kislev* - 30 days each
*Tevet* - 29 days
*Shvat* - 30 days
*Adar* - 29 days
*Nisan* - 30 days
*Iyar* - 28 days (*Yom Yerushalayim* is on the 28th day of *Iyar*)